# api's used to get data from user pc's in lab monitoring software

Tags: java

i want to monitor labs computer from administrators computer. what sort of API's can i use to make this kind of product or to get data from clients computer to admin computer.

Comment: What kind of monitiring do you mean? There are plenty different options, and it would be good if you clarified what it is, exactly, that you want to do.

Comment: Monitoring like live monitoring(user login activity,application monitoring,view live screens,screenshots in absence of admin in the lab,bandwidth control(so that no user can use torrent or other things),pop-up messages on an unauthorized access(websites,files),file folder changes, view printed documents,which documents are opened by clients.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things, i.e.:

- What kind of data you want to collect
- The OS of the computers you want to monitor
- The permissions you have to run commands or install software on those computers

One of the most popular tools for monitoring is [Nagios](https://www.nagios.org/), and it's an open source project. It supports multiple protocols and is very flexible/configurable. AFAIK most protocols involve invoking some sort of remote command on the monitored system via SSH (NRPE) or HTTP.

However, there are many other tools (Cacti, Zabbix, OP5...), either free or commercial. Just find the one that fulfills your requirements.

On the other hand if you just want to monitor network equipment, SNMP is the protocol of choice.

Comment: Sir i cant use preexisting softwares i want to make this product as a final year project thats why i need to know some general API's used to get data

Comment: "AFAIK most protocols involve invoking some sort of remote command on the monitored system via SSH or HTTP", and maybe a client installed to recognize those remote commands.